# Audio signal Processing-Retrieving information from audio

Tags: android, signal-processing

Is it possible to retrieve some information like some id from the audio signal ?

Comment: Please provide some more information.

Comment: Detecting the ultrasound emitted and extracting the information form that. The information is something like id=01.

Comment: "Detecting the ultrasound emitted" - What does this mean? Audio signals would not record ultrasound. Sampling rates do not allow that since audio signals are used to record only that which lies within the spectrum of audibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be sure of what information you want from the audio file and if the format that the audio signal is in supports the storage of meta data.

The following formats have some data associated with them:
1. wav: You may need to read the wav header for getting data such as sampling rate, bytes per sample etc.
2. mp3: Each mp3 file comes with an ID3 tag. These ID3 tags contain information such as date of recording, artist, album, track etc. These tags are optional and not all mp3 files may have them. You will need to find a good ID3 editor/reader to get at this information. A good place to start can be [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/).

Take a look at the android documentation. There may be something inbuilt (especially for wav formats - sampling rate etc.) already.

HTH,
Sriram.

Comment: an upvote would be nice too! ;)